# Mysql stored procedure to fetch data and return as row

Tags: mysql, procedure

I have a stored procedure as like below.

In this procedure, query should return a row based on the matching of name; but when I try to use this SR, query is not fetching and SR is not executing successfully. Please let me know my error?

```
DROP TABLE TEMP;

CREATE TABLE TEMP
(
NAME VARCHAR(15)
);

INSERT INTO TEMP ( SELECT DISTINCT(NAME) FROM IMDETAILS);

DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE INCIDENT()
BEGIN

DECLARE NAMEE VARCHAR(10);

DECLARE CUR1 CURSOR for SELECT NAME FROM TEMP;

open CUR1;

read_loop: LOOP

FETCH CUR1  INTO NAMEE;

SELECT NAMEE;

insert into incident values ((select distinct(NAME) from IMDETAILS where NAME=NAMEE),

(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM IMDETAILS WHERE NAME=NAMEE AND RESOLVED_DATE=(SELECT CURDATE()) AND STATUS='RESOLVED'),

(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM IMDETAILS WHERE NAME=NAMEE AND RESOLVED_WEEK = WEEK(CURDATE()) AND STATUS='RESOLVED'),

(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM IMDETAILS WHERE NAME=NAMEE AND RESOLVED_MONTH=(SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%M')) AND STATUS='RESOLVED'),

(SELECT POINTS FROM POINT WHERE IMCOUNT<=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM IMDETAILS WHERE NAME=NAMEE AND RESOLVED_MONTH=(SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%M'))
AND STATUS='RESOLVED' )));

END LOOP;
CLOSE CUR1;

END $$;

DELIMITER;
```

Comment: FInal delimiter statement should be Delimiter ;

Comment: Can you add sample data and the call statement?

Comment: i have IMDETAILS table  with columns as "NAME","DAILY COUNT","WEEKELY COUNT',"MONTHLY COUNT". i have temp table with column as "NAME".so in  my store procedure ,names in the temp table should match with the names in the IMDETAILS table based on their daily,weekely,month count.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your problem is that 0 rows are returned from the cursor. Try amending your code to include a done declaration, a continue handler declaration and a done test. for example

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS INCIDENT;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `INCIDENT`()
    LANGUAGE SQL
    NOT DETERMINISTIC
    CONTAINS SQL
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
    COMMENT ''
BEGIN
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE NAMEE VARCHAR(10);
DECLARE CUR1 CURSOR for SELECT distinct NAME FROM TEMP;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS INCIDENTS;
CREATE TABLE INCIDENTS(NAME VARCHAR(3),RESOLVED_DATE_COUNT INT);

open CUR1;
read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH CUR1  INTO NAMEE;

        if done then leave read_loop; end if;

        #SELECT NAMEE;
        insert into incidents values 
        (
        NAMEE,

        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM IMDETAILS WHERE NAME=NAMEE AND RESOLVED_DATE= CURDATE() AND STATUS='RESOLVED')

        #(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM IMDETAILS WHERE NAME=NAMEE AND RESOLVED_WEEK = WEEK(CURDATE()) AND STATUS='RESOLVED'),
        #(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM IMDETAILS WHERE NAME=NAMEE AND RESOLVED_MONTH=(SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%M')) AND STATUS='RESOLVED'),
        #(SELECT POINTS FROM POINT WHERE IMCOUNT<=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM IMDETAILS WHERE NAME=NAMEE AND RESOLVED_MONTH=(SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%M'))
        #AND STATUS='RESOLVED' ))
        );

END LOOP;
CLOSE CUR1;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Note I have also changed the cursor select statement to a select distinct, the insert statement to select namee (there does not seem much point in rereading imdetails when you already know this) and amended the first select to remove the unnecessary select for curdate.
so given

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS IMDETAILS;

CREATE TABLE IMDETAILS(NAME VARCHAR(3),RESOLVED_DATE DATE, STATUS VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO IMDETAILS VALUES
('ABC','2016-10-10','RESOLVED'),('ABC','2016-10-10',NULL),('ABC','2016-10-10','RESOLVED'),('ABC','2016-10-10','RESOLVED'),
('DEF','2016-10-10',NULL),('DEF','2016-10-10',NULL),('DEF','2016-10-10',NULL),('DEF','2016-10-10','RESOLVED');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TEMP;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEMP AS
SELECT NAME FROM IMDETAILS  WHERE NAME = 'ABC';

CALL INCIDENT();

SELECT * FROM INCIDENTS;
```

results in

```
+------+---------------------+
| NAME | RESOLVED_DATE_COUNT |
+------+---------------------+
| ABC  |                   3 |
+------+---------------------+
```